# Why does the Mac App Store show an "error" for a missing product?

Tags: mac-appstore, install, error

A game that purchased a while ago in the Mac App Store is now "not currently available in the U.S. store", but continues to appear in my Applications folder as a download in progress

[image]

and shows an error in the App Store's list of apps that I've purchased

[image]

Why does this app continue to appear in the App Store if it is no longer available? What can I do to get rid of the warning about the error in the App Store? I've tired deleting the app (or what's left of it) from my machine, but it continues to appear in the App Store as an error.

---

And if anyone knows, I'm curious why the app is no longer available.

Comment: I guess they removed from public this application for some reason. I don't know why.

Comment: @EirNym: Evidently, but I wonder why the Store doesn't handle such a scenario more gracefully. It's really no error at all if that's the case.

Comment: hided or removed application is same thing for user: it is impossible to do something with it, and application should give directions. The best way they find is to move to "main page", or show error if you try to look via web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Mavericks will fix this bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you disconnect all network cables and turn off WiFi, you should be able to reboot and have the download fail. At that point, deleting the file should be the permanent solution.

Once that's sorted, you'll have better luck hiding that purchase to avoid a re-download attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Killing the process "Storeagent" from Activity Monitor helps sometime.